# How to remove parentheses and replace "white space" with "-" in php using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

This is What I Have - Huawei MatePad 11 (2021)

This is what I want - Huawei-MatePad-11-2021

This is what I have done so far. (only it replaces "white space" with "-".

```
echo preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '-', $test);
```

I want to remove parentheses, and want to replace "white space" with "-" at once. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'Huawei MatePad 11 (2021)';
$text = preg_replace('/[(|)]/', '', preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $text));

echo($text);
```

Comment: Ur welcome. Could you accept this answer?

Answer (score 1):

```php
$test = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '-', $test); # Replace space
$test = preg_replace('/[\(|\)]+/', '', $test);      # Replace parenthesis 

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a single pattern with preg_replace_callback and match from an opening till closing parenthesis.

```
\(([^()]+)\)|\h+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `([^()]+)` Capture **group 1** match 1+ chars other than `(` `)`
- `\)` Match `)`
- `|` Or
- `\h+` Match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/1gbDS) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8r1b5x/1)

For example return group 1 using `$m[1]` if it exists, else return `-`

```
$s = "Huawei MatePad 11 (2021)";
$regex = "/\(([^()]+)\)|\h+/";
$result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m) {
    return array_key_exists(1, $m) ? $m[1] : '-';
}, $s);
echo $result;
```

Output

```
Huawei-MatePad-11-2021
```